# The node js server is not loading my website files

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipeer-connectivity

When I run node index.js the browser loads only the html, disregarding javascript, images, and css , and if I try to access a link it shows a blank plage: node.js Cannot GET /login.html, how do I fix that?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http); 
var myList = new Array();
var i = 0;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html', {});
});
```

Comment: where are you telling node to serve the login.html page? the code above seems to only serve the index.html page. Have you tried another route?

Comment: It sounds like you want to serve a bunch of static files. You say "the browser loads only the html, disregarding javascript, images, and css".
If you want to serve a whole directory you should look into the static middleware: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

Answer (score 0):

You need show the error with your question and "/login.html" file?

Or quick-fix, you can change your code as below:

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html', {});
```

to

```
res.render('index.html', { /*data*/ });
```

Comment: What good will that do? It still only handles the request for `/`.

Answer (score -1):

Here you have some code to tell your server what to when when the browser requests `/`.

> ```
> app.get('/'
> ```

You haven't written anything to tell it what to do when the browser requests `/login.html`. Write something for that case.