# Local files error linking in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I seem to be having a lot of trouble with local js files.

whenever I link a local file to my index.html,

The console generated this error for every one of them

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

However, linking the files online seem to work fine.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I'm positive the file-paths are correct, double-checked that first. 
I've also tried moving some files to the same folder as the html file, but still not getting resolved.

I've read that it might be an encoding issue, but I've added

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

to the header already.

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:  ALSO, I was having problems with bootstrap.min.css until I switched to using an online copy. Local copy failed for that, too.**

Comment: what if you call your scripts beginning from the root directory `<script type="text/javascript" src="/1st_level_subdir/2nd_level_subdir/angular/app.js"></script>` ?

Comment: close the meta tag

Comment: tried calling from root directory just now, no luck.  meta tag wasn't copied over properly, fixed.

Comment: If you check the console.log in your server terminal, you might be able to figure out which one is missing

Comment: add a screenshot of the errorl

Comment: Are the files in a folder two directories above  `index.html` document ?

Comment: app.js seems to a customized js file. Also is there any reference of jquery methods or bootstrap items inside app.js?

Comment: Add some pics to help. As shown in the second picture, jquery.min.js is located 2 folders up and in the bootstrap folder. All file-paths should be right. As for the angular files, they are currently not doing anything, no references inside. Some weird file linking problem. Only local files have problems.

Comment: @user1869558 — Open the Network tab. Look at the URLs that are being requested to fetch the JS. Look at the web server your are using and see how it is handling those URLs. Given the port number you are using, I wouldn't be surprised if this was a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776556/the-node-js-server-is-not-loading-my-website-files

Comment: Run your html through a validator. You have two title tags.